# Is there a way to define a PYthon function parameter list by a string?

Tags: python

Is it possible to define a Python function parameter list by a string like the following?:

```
param_list = "alpha, beta = 100, *args"

def my_func(param_list):
   return 100
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. You are passing a string as an argument, not any "list of parameters". Would you have an example on how the program shall use this "list as a string" ?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want to accomplish. While it may be possible to do exactly what you're asking for, it probably isn't a suitable solution to what you want to do. For starters, explain what's lacking about args and kwargs.

Comment: Please show what's the _real_ problem here. Why would you want to do such as thing?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a reasonable way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you, for some reason, want to be able to redefine the function parameters using a string, you can do it, but it'd require using eval() and string formatting.

Shorthand example:

```
#since you can do:
def a():
    return 1

def b():
    return 2

a = b
#a() returns 2 now, because calls to a() are actually calls to b() now

#you can also do:
a = eval("def a({str_of_args}): \n    return 3")

#a(proper arguments) now returns 3
```

Having said that, I cannot think of any case where this would actually be *a good idea*. It's an ugly hack 99.9% of the time, and if you HAVE to do that, it should be taken as a sign something is likely seriously wrong with the design as a whole.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would need to split the string and read the 'parameters'. <strike>There is no way for python to translate your string to parameters.</strike>  Guess you could use eval... but its ugly.

What you could do is build a string

```
"my_func(alpha, beta = 100, *args)"
```

and eval it:

```
eval("my_func(alpha, beta = 100, *args)")
```

You can also do this:

```
my_func(eval("alpha, beta = 100, *args"))
```

However, you may want to make changes to your function because this will give you an error as is.

If you are passing a variable number of objects, use args that is what it is there for.

Comment: There's probably a way to edit the parameters or at least replace the function with one created at a later time. args and/or kwargs are probably the appropriate tool here though. ("there's no way for python to ..." is a really strong statement)

Comment: I guess if you wanted to, you could put executable python code in the string and have it run that but there is no point to it and is in fact quite dangerous.

Comment: It's not dangerous unless you're executing untrusted code. There's also quite a lot of introspection/meta programming available in python allowing for manipulating function objects.

Comment: Yes, but who knows what those variables are being set to. If they are being set to something defined by user input then it is very dangerous. Plus there is no need to use eval or exec for what they are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass variable number of parameters like this:

```
def someMethod(*listOfStringParameters):
    for i in listOfStringParameters:
        print(i)

someMethod("alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta")
```

Output:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```